# re/si face of alkenes

Tags: stereochemistry

How to determine whether the face of the attached alkene is re or si?
If assigning priorities in regard to the left C atom it is re, but for the right C atom it is si. How is it actually determined?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure that this depends *on the atom attacked*. Most attacks on double bond are stepwise to a certain extent. And even when they aren’t, the absolute configuration should be discussed on a per-atom basis.

But if you have a concerted reaction and want to label both: (2*si*,3*re*).

Comment: Is there any other way to label them? If the alkyl chains are too complex, it isn't easy to determine the locants of these C atoms (like 2 and 3 in the given example).

Comment: Not that I know of =C @Marko.

Comment: So it is obligatory to know the name of the compound with all the locants to be able to name the face properly.